# Let $A_1, A_2, \dots \in \mathcal{A}$. Show that if $\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i) > 0$, then $\mu(A_i) > 0$, for some $i$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Let $A_1, A_2, \dots \in \mathcal{A}$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is a sigma-algebra. Show that if $\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i) > 0$, then $\mu(A_i) > 0$, for some $i$.

I know that the measure must be positive so at least $\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i) \ge 0$. Now since the sets $A_i$ belong to sigma-algebra I can have that $$\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(A_i) = \mu(A_1) + \mu (A_2) + \dots.$$

Each of the terms in the sum is greater than or equal to $0$ so if the $\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i)  >0$, then at least one of the summands must be greater than zero say $\mu(A_j) >0$ for some $j \in \{i, \dots \}$.

I feel like this is not really correct solution. What can I do here to prove this?

Comment: $\mu (\cup_i A_i) \leq \sum \mu(A_i)$.

Comment: I think you are not that far off. The equality you wrote down corresponds to $\sigma$-additivity, which you do have in a measure space but only for pairwise disjoint sets, which you don't necessarily have here. But the union bound (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality) might be helpful...

Comment: In a sigma-algebra shouldn’t I be able to disjointize the sets $A_i$ without any problems?

Comment: @JimingLe Yes, what you can do is define $B_1 = A_1$ and $B_i = A_i \setminus B_{i-1}$, then you get disjoint sets which have the same union, i.e., $\bigcup A_i = \bigcup B_i$. I think you can argue this way, but using the union bound might be quicker and cleaner. In any case, the union bound is used all over the place so it's definitely good to familiarize yourself with it.